# How to implement a single button for all gridview in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a button at the bottom of the gridview where items are displayed for that i am using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
      <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <GridView
           android:id="@+id/list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@android:color/white"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
           android:numColumns="auto_fit"
           android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
           android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
           android:columnWidth="90dp" >
     </GridView>
    <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="60dp"
          android:layout_height="100dp" />
   <TextView android:id="@+id/caption"
             android:layout_below="@id/image"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="Go "
     android:textSize="20dip"
     android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But for this i am getting a button for item in a gridview could anyone tell me how to set a single button for all the items in the gridview at the bottom

```
 http://i.imgur.com/QwdYJ.jpg>
```

Comment: can you post some screen shot how you want and how the current one is displayed.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QwdYJ.jpg @Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i used this but i am getting button for each and every item @santhosh

Comment: what do u mean each and every item ? are you using this layout in some Adapter class to load grid items?

Comment: so, inside a gridview your girditem includes gridview, imageView, a Button and TextView. Seriously Y? usually there will be a layout file X in which there is a gridview. and for the adapter to load girditems a layout file Y will be created. But, you are having a gridView in "Y" which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: i am only loading image and textview ..There is no need to load Button it should be at the bottom of the layout

Comment: create a layout file "layout1.xml". place a gridview and below it place a button. use linear layout as parent. and set layout_weight=1 for gridView. And then create layout2.xml (for gridItem) for adapter and place text view and image in layout2.xml. and in getView() method of the adapter set text and image for each item.